# Composer version requirement

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I have to required libraries in my composer
The first one requires illuminate/support version 6 and another one require illuminate/support version 5.8.9

In this case what I should do?

Thanks

Comment: what libraries are you using? im sure the library that supports version 5.8 has a upgraded version as well, if they dont then there is no use installing a deprecated library in your project, look for a alternative library that is still active.

Answer (score 0):

Composer doesn't support multiple versions of the same package in a project.

The easiest solution is probably to just use the same library version throughout the project. Or you can fork one and include the repo in your composer.json.

Comment: So i need to change the library and use a compatible one?